# Determine which of the following ideals are prime, maximal ideal or neither in the polynomial ring $C[x,y]$

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals

1. $I_{1}=(x)$, 2. $I_{2}=(x,y^{2})$, 3. $I_{3}=(x-y,x+y)$, 4. $I_{4}=(x-y,x^{2}-y^{2})$.

My Attempt:
It is easy to check that $I_{1}$ is prime but not maximal ideal.

For $I_{2}$, clearly $y^{2} \in (x,y^{2})$, but y,y does not belong to $(x,y^{2})$. THis implies $I_{2}$ is not prime ideal. Similarly, $I_{4}$ is not prime ideal.

$I_{3}$ is both prime and maximal ideal(not sure about $I_{3}$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just want to know is my answer is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your answers for $I_1,I_2,I_3$ are correct.

For $I_3$, it's easily verified that $(x-y,x+y)=(x,y)$, which is clearly maximal.

Your answer for $I_4$ is not correct, since
$$I_4=(x-y,x^2-y^2)=(x-y)$$
which is prime (but not maximal).

Comment: Can I say $I_{4} \subset I_{3}$, then it is not maximal.

Comment: Yes, it's a proper subset since, for example, $x\in I_3$ but $x\not\in I_4$.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for your help.